# How i can navigate in an another page with a react.component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, httprequest, react-native-navigation

I'm a beginner with react and I want use it for sand a form and change the page. This is my code:

```
class Home extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {type: true, number: true};
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }
  handleChange(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.type === 'type' ? target.checked : target.value;
    const name = target.name;
    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    });
  }
  async handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    try{
      await axios.post("http://localhost:5000/number",{
        type: this.state.type,
        number: this.state.number
      });
    }catch(error){
        console.log(error)
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="tabSearch">
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <select className="input" value={this.state.value} name="type" onChange={this.handleChange}>
          <option className="first_select" value="">0</option>.
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
          </select>
          <select className="input" value={this.state.value} name="number" onChange={this.handleChange}>
            <option className="first_select" value="">number</option>.
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="0">0</option>
          </select>
        <input className="button" type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Home;
```

I tried to use "Navigate" but it gives me some problems because I use a react.component, so I wanted to know how to solve this problem pls T.T

Answer (score 1):

You can use react router.
Official docs: https://reactrouter.com/en/main